# How to cast java.lang.Class to POJO Entity class?

Tags: java, casting

I want to cast `java.lang.Class` to `POJO` `Entity` class?
So I could pass `Entity class` as a `parameter` to method that I don't want to writer seprate method for each `Entity class` operation like searching `id.`

My code is as follow:

```
public Class isIdExist(int id, Class cls) {
    Class clas = cls;
    try ( Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Class> cq = (CriteriaQuery<Class>) cb.createQuery(clas);

        Root root = cq.from(clas);
        cq.where(cb.equal(root.get("id"), id));
        clas = session.createQuery(cq).uniqueResult();
    }
    return clas;
}
```

Client code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    BLManager bLManager = new BLManager();

    bLManager.isIdExist(1, Citizen.class);
```

}

But I'm getting:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class practice.pojo.Citizen cannot be cast to class java.lang.Class
```

For easy understanding I tried as follow:

```
    Class cls = Citizen.class;

    System.out.println("Citizen to java.lang.Class: " + cls);

    Citizen citizen = (Citizen.class.cast(cls));

    System.err.println("java.lang.Class to Citizen: " + citizen);  
   // also tried  
   Citizen citizen = (Citizen) cls; //compile time error.
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `Class`, you can only use `Class`, not any java class.
What you need to do is use generic type to pass the actual class you want:

```
public <T> T isIdExist(int id, Class<T> cls) {
    try ( Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<T> cq = (CriteriaQuery<T>) cb.createQuery(cls);

        Root root = cq.from(cls);
        cq.where(cb.equal(root.get("id"), id));
        return session.createQuery(cq).uniqueResult();
    }
}
```